# Как правильно обновлять приложение?

Tags: c#, .net

Пишу клиентское приложение на C# .NET. После релиза, естественно, будут доработки. Как правильно обновлять приложение? Есть вариант скачивать исполняемый файл (exe/dll), который уже будет обновлять приложение, и запускать его. Но не будут ли ругаться антивирусы на такие действия ПО?

Comment: Если проект состоит из 1 файла, то можно качать и заменять оригинал, этого вполне достаточно должно быть. Если файлов больше 1, то либо делаем какую нибудь "карту" с версиями и измененными файлами, либо тупо архивом передаем все файлы и заменяем. В обоих вариантах я бы использовал какое нибудь сжатие. Если у вас огромный проект, на несколько GB, то можно посмотреть в сторону P2P (Toorent). Я лично обновляю путем скачивания архива и проблем не замечал, не с антивирусами, ни с чем либо другим. Пробовал обновить игровой клиент (10гб), на сервере каждый файл сжимал в архив, проблем тоже не было.

Comment: Аваст будет любой новых EXE файл запускать в песочнице. Если вы будете запускать это файл с флагами, то большая вероятность того, что функционал приложения в песочнице будет сильно урезан.

Comment: @Rootware а какая разница какая функциональность в песочнице? Мне главное, чтобы ПО обновлялось.

Comment: ClickOnce посмотрите, как вариант

Comment: @J.Huxley функционал в песочнице сильно урезан. Например удалить предыдущий `EXE` файл не получится. А также воспользоваться функциями `System.Management` (как пример) у вас не получится, словите исключение.

Comment: Достаточно часто применяем вариант, когда приложение при запуске проверяет на внешнем API наличие обновлений. Скачивает из само и переподкладывает сборки вместо текущих. В лоб подменить сборки не получится, т.к. они заняты, но можно воспользоваться теневым копированием или переименованием запущенных сборок (удалять запущенные сборки нельзя, а переименовывать можно).

Comment: Если десктоп, то попробуйте [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows). Он как ClickOnce, но работает.

Comment: @KirillRunk спасибо, полезнаая вещь.